Getting a number of items from a list by pagination in Dynamodb
I have a dynamodb structure like below:
    {
       "PK" : "queue#1234#view",
       "SK" : "board#1234",
       "items" : [
           "1234",
           "1234",
           "1234",
           "1234",
           "1234",
           "1234"
        ]
    }

I want to know if there is a way to use a filter expression in Dynamodb to get range of items from the list for pagination by specifying indexes. For example, I want to get range items from index 0 to 3 and index 2 - 5. I was reading through this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html but couldn't find a solution. There is a list expression function: list_append, and I'd like to know if there is a function like list_select[start_index, end_index] or something similar.


There is no real advantage to do a filter on a single item... You pay the same, and the performance is the same. So it's best just to read the entire item and manipulate it on the client side as you wish.

Gotcha! Thank you @Leeroy

But is there a way to use a filter expression in that way to get a sub list of the list?

You can get an individual element but not a range. So if you knew you needed index[0,1,2] then you'd project each of those as individual elements

So that would be 3 queries to get index[0,1,2] and not one then?

No one query, but 3 elements in your projection expression.
